# Asynchronus assertion in javascript testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing

I'm trying to test a react project, and I have the following asynchronous test that should fail here: `fail("Fail: " + response.status)`

What do I need to do to make this happen?

```
describe('Test dummy data endpoint', () => {
        it('Test postman-echo for 2 element todo list', (done) => {
                var options = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(["One", "Two"])
                }
                var promise = fetch('https://postman-echo.com/post', options);
                promise.then(
                    function (response) {
                        it('Status should be 200', (stschk) => {
                            fail("Fail: " + response.status)
                            stschk()
                        })
                        return response.json()
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        fail("Failed", error)
                    }
                )
                done()
            }
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: Is this code not working? How is it not working? What have you tried?

Comment: Well, like the question says, I'm expecting it to fail at the line that says `fail("Fail: " + response.status)`.  It's not failing there, it's passing.  I'm not sure what else to say about it, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that's looking, here's how to do it:

```
describe('Test ajax', () => {
    it('Test postman-echo for 2 element todo list', (asdf) => {
        expect.assertions(2)
        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(["One", "Two"])
        }
        fetch('https://postman-echo.com/post', options).then(
            function (data) {
                expect(data.status).toEqual(200)
                data.json().then((jd) => {
                    expect(jd.data.length).toEqual(2)
                    asdf()
                })
            }
        )
    })
})
```